# How to determine exchange rate dynamics in currency derivatives

Tags: stochastic-calculus, itos-lemma, currency, numerairechange, girsanov

I need some guidance regarding exchange rate dynamics in currency derivatives.

Following three dynamics are defined below,

$\frac{dS(t)}{S(t)}=\alpha dt+\sigma dW(t)$ ; the stock dynamics in the **foreign** market

$\frac{dB_d(t)}{B_d(t)}=r_ddt$ ; the **domestic** money account

$\frac{dX(t)}{X(t)}=\alpha_X dt+\sigma_X dW(t)$ ; the **domestic/foreign** exchange rate

My goal is to derive the dynamics of $X$ under the equivalent martingale measure where the domestic money account is the numeraire.

**My solution so far:**

**Step 1**: I can define the foreign asset in the domestic economy as $S_d(t)=S(t)X(t)$ since we have the domestic/foreign exhange rate. Under the domestic economy and the domestic money account as numeraire I can further define the following martingale (normalized money process); $Z(t):=\frac{S(t)X(t)}{B_d(t)}$

**Step 2:** Applying Itô's lemma gives me,

$dZ(t)=\frac{X(t)}{B_d(t)}dS(t)+\frac{S(t)}{B_d(t)}dX(t)-\frac{S(t)X(t)}{B_d^2(t)}dB_d(t)+..........$

**My first question here is whether I am thinking correctly defining the normalized money process $Z(t)$. The second question is how the cross-variation terms will fair? Should not the cross-variation terms be equal to $0$ since the return rate $r_d $in the domestic money account is deterministic?**

**Step 3:** Should the normalized money process $Z(t)$ be correctly defined and I have solved the first order differentiation of $Z(t)$ i.e. $dZ(t)$ I want to apply a girsanov transform to the p.m. $Q^d$ with the girsanov kernel $\psi$.

**Step 4:** Insert $dW(t)=\psi dt+dW^{Q^d}(t)$ into the exchange rate $X$.

Comment: It appears correct. Can you complete $dZ(t)$?

Comment: @Gordon no unfortunately I do not know how to handle the cross-variation terms. Any hints? Thank you :)

Comment: You have both $X$ and $S$ here. Do you want the dynamics of $X$ or $S$?

Comment: @Gordon I wish to know the dynamics for $X$. However, I do not know how to complete step 2, i.e. find the cross-cariation terms. Appreciate your time man.

Comment: Then you need to consider $\frac{X(t) B_f(t)}{B_d(t)}$, rather than $\frac{X(t)S(t)}{B_d(t)}$, and make sure it is a martingale under the domestic risk-neutral measure.

Comment: But what if $B_f(t)$ is not defined in the problem? only $X$ $S$ and $B_d$ is defined. I need to somehow find $X$ under the EMM where the domestic market is numeraire with these information only.